# Problem in 2D heat equation solution using FDM in Matlab

Tags: matlab, pde

I am trying to solve the 2D time dependent heat equation using finite difference method in Matlab. The code is below:

```
%Spatial variable on x direction
Lx=1;
delta=0.1;
xmin=-Lx/2;
xmax=Lx/2;
Nx=(xmax-xmin)/delta;
x=linspace(xmin,xmax,Nx);

%Spatial variable on y direction
Ly=1;
delta=0.1;
ymin=-Ly/2;
ymax=Ly/2;
Ny=(ymax-ymin)/delta;
y=linspace(ymin,ymax,Ny);

%Total matrix size
N = (Nx * Ny);

%Time variable
dt=0.002;
tmin=0;
tmax=1;
nt=(tmax-tmin)/dt;
tspan=linspace(tmin,tmax,nt);

%Create a meshgrid
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);

% Defining initial state:
T0=exp(-(X.^2+Y.^2)); 

%reshape the initial condition to a vector
T_reshape = reshape(T0,N,1);

% Constructing the 1D spatial matrix
A=zeros(N,N);
I = eye(N);
%the diagonal elements
for m=1:N %the number of rows
for n=1:N  %the number of columns
if (m==n)
A(m,n)=-2/delta^2; 
end
%Boundary conditions: A(1,N)==A(N,1)
if(n==N)&&(m==1)
A(m,n)=1;
end
if(n==1)&&(m==N)
A(m,n)=1;
end
end
end
%the off-diagonal elements
for n=1:N-1 
A(n+1,n)=1/delta^2; %the value of each lower off-diagonal elements
end 
for n=2:N
A(n-1,n)=1/delta^2; %the value of each upper off-diagonal element
end

%create the 2D matrix
B = kron(A,I)+kron(I,A);

% Solve the equation
[Time,Tem]=ode45('dTDistribution',tspan,T_reshape,[],B,delta);
```

The function that is being called here is as following:

```
%Define the function
function dT=dTDistribution(tspan,T_reshape,dummy,B,delta)
dT = B.*T_reshape; 
end
```

My problem is that the dimension of my matrix `B` is different than the dimensions of the initial condition `T_reshape`, therefore, the multiplication of `B.*T_reshape` won't be possible. I'm wondering how can I change the dimension of `T_reshape` to make the multiplication valid. Hope anyone could help.

Thank you.

Comment: `size(B) =  10000       10000` and `size(T_reshape) = 100     1`. Of course, they would not multiply. You should be knowing what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to achieve this multiplication so I can solve the heat equation. However, this change in dimensionality prevents this and I am wondering how can I remedy this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for looking at my problem, but I have figured out the mistake in the code. Since `A` is the 1D matrix, then its size should be either `(Nx,Nx)` or `(Ny,Ny)` and then when taking the tensor product to get `B` the 2D matrix its size will be `(N,N)`.  However in the code, `A` has the size of `(N,N)` and as a result `B` is blowing up making the multiplication afterwards not possible.

Thanks.